# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError : Type error

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am running "php artisan botman:list-drivers -v" command in my laravel 5.6 project and getting this error thrown out:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Type error:
>   Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Table::setRows()
>   must be of the type array, object given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php
>   on line 411
>
> ```
> at C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\symfony\console\Helper\Table.php: 222
>     218|
>     219|         return $this;
>     220|     }
>     221|
>
>     222|     public function setRows(array $rows)
>     223|     {
>     224|         $this->rows = array();
>     225|
>     226|         return $this->addRows($rows);
> ```
>
> Exception trace:
>
> 1
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\Table::setRows(Object(Tightenco\Collect\Support\Collection))
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php
>   : 411
>
> 2
>   Illuminate\Console\Command::table(Object(Tightenco\Collect\Support\Collection))
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\botman\studio-addons\src\Console\Commands\BotManListDrivers.php
>   : 74
>
> 3   BotMan\Studio\Console\Commands\BotManListDrivers::handle()
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php
>   : 29
>
> 4   call_user_func_array([])
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php
>   : 29
>
> 5
>   Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container{closure}()
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php
>   : 87
>
> 6
>   Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application),
>   Object(Closure))
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php
>   : 31
>
> 7
>   Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application),
>   [])
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
>   : 564
>
> 8   Illuminate\Container\Container::call()
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php
>   : 183
>
> 9
>   Illuminate\Console\Command::execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php :
>   252
>
> 10 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php
>   : 170
>
> 11 
>   Illuminate\Console\Command::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php : 865
>
> 12 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRunCommand(Object(BotMan\Studio\Console\Commands\BotManListDrivers),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php : 241
>
> 13 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application::doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php : 143
>
> 14 
>   Symfony\Component\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php
>   : 88
>
> 15 
>   Illuminate\Console\Application::run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php
>   : 121
>
> 16 
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput),
>   Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
>         C:\xampp\htdocs\chatbot\artisan : 37

Is there any solution? I am working in new laravel project and am not able to figure out the problem location.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `$rows` which is an object to `setRows` function which is looking for an array.

Comment: But that's the thing. I haven't done anything yet. It's a brand new laravel project

Comment: where did you defined the row property?

Comment: All I did is ran "composer create-project laravel/laravel project-name" then this command.